# Parsing bits from a 128 byte block of hex in Python

Tags: python, parsing, hex, bit-manipulation, computer-science

Ok, so I am in a bit of a weird parsing scenario, but here it goes.

I have a script that reads in the bytes it needs to parse. I need to parse out those bytes and then return them.

## Example

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Description: Log Parameters   : Byte Offset:  0
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Description: Offset           : Byte Offset:  2-1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Description: Request Count    : Byte Offset:  3
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Description: Reserved         : Byte Offset:  127-4
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So my script will eventually have the ability to output the hex associated with each line. For now, I need to say, ok, Byte offset is 0, go get the first byte and return it in hex. Ok, byte offset is 127-4, go get that, print the hex value right there on the screen.

The format is 127 bytes of hex stored in a string.

## HEX String

```
100000000000000220000000000000003000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000
```

The 0x prefix has been stripped and stored into a string.

There are a lot of zeroes in this example, but this is just a random case.
The byte offsets can fluctuate, so I'm trying to figure out how to basically iterate through an array of byte offsets and parse them incrementally.

It's weird to me that if a description takes up so many bytes, bitwise operations become more difficult because I can't split these up into 32 or even 64 bit blocks.

## What I Want

Currently I have an array of the byte offsets in the following form:

```
[0, 2-1, 3, 127-4]
```

I want to iterate through each of those byte offsets, parse them from long hex string and print them.

## Question

How do I use the byte offsets from my array and parse them out of the hex string.

Comment: So your question is how to parse the list of byte offsets?  Or how to use those to get the correct bytes from the string of hexadecimal bytes?

Comment: How are you storing the range?  `2-1` is a subtraction in Python.

Comment: Their docs are weird, but it's actually 2-1 (2 and 1 included)

Comment: @Ryan, StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site. Readers, such as yourself, ask questions. Other readers attempt to answer them. Your post is well-organized, and you've clearly put some effort into it. However, it is still missing a key ingredient: a question. Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: Sorry, was trying my best to structure this best as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that you have the starting byte # stored in `start` variable, and ending byte # stored in `end` variable, and then the hex string stored in `string` variable.

Since every byte is two hexadecimal digits, you can simply do this to get the byte in hexadecimal string form:

```
string[start*2:(end+1)*2]
```

You need to do `end+1` because it appears that your byte ranges are inclusive in your example, but Python slicing is exclusive on the end of the range.  [More on slicing if you're unfamiliar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

To make this concrete for you, here is a minimal working example.  You may have to do parsing and massaging to get your ranges to look like mine, but this is the idea:

```
string = "100000000000000220000000000000003000000000000000" \
         "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" \
         "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" \
         "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" \
         "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" \
         "0000000000000000"

ranges = ['0', '2-1', '3', '127-4']

for offset in ranges:
    offset_list = offset.split('-')
    if len(offset_list) == 1:
        start = int(offset_list[0])
        end = int(offset_list[0])
    else:
        start = int(offset_list[1])
        end = int(offset_list[0])
    the_bytes = string[start*2:(end+1)*2]
    print('%d-%d: %s' % (start, end, the_bytes))
```

Output:

```
0-0: 10
1-2: 0000
3-3: 00
4-127: 00000002200000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a more concrete example that you can directly run.  Hopefully that'll help you a bit more!

Comment: Know the easiest way to split a string of 127-4 into a comma-sep. list like that? nvm, got it

Comment: @Ryan `"127-4".split("-")`

Comment: Hm, I am overcomplicating this. I am looking through each byte offset in a loop. As it iterates, I want to append '127-4' into the form [(4,127)] so the final array looks like the ranges example above

Comment: Also slight problem in your example output. Bits are read in reverse order, so shouldn't I reverse the string?

Comment: See my updated code, which deals with the ranges being strings, as you seem to be implying.  Also, if you are saying that the bytes are numbered from 127 down to 0, then yes, you should reverse `string` before doing this.

Comment: Hm, I noticed a slight issue. The bits are printing in reverse order LSB - MSB when it should be MSB - LSB. Can this be fixed? I think it's ok to structure "the_bytes" as the_bytes[::-1]

Comment: That is probably caused by the fact that you reversed the string.  Since each byte is a pair of digits (say, AB), when you reversed the string, the digits were reversed as well (AB becomes BA).  So, you should actually reverse the string in units of pairs.

Comment: Here is the shortest way I could come up with:

`string = "".join(x for pair in reversed(list(zip(string[::2], string[1::2]))) for x in pair)`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Input: array of byte values
x='''
100000000000000220000000000000003000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000
'''

# Input: list of offsets
o = ['0', '2-1', '3', '127-4']

# Put everything in a more useful format
x = ''.join(x.split())
o = [item.split('-') for item in o]
o = [[int(item) for item in pair] for pair in o]
for pair in o:
    if len(pair) == 1:
        pair.append(pair[0])

# Display the values
for pair in o:
    print pair, x[pair[1]*2:pair[0]*2+2]
```

Comment: my output from this... slightly off maybe?

Comment: [0, 0] 0x
[2, 1] 0000
[3, 3] 00
[127, 4] 0000000000

Comment: Your input string apparently starts with `0x`, but the example input string in your question doesn't. If your actual data has an `0x`, or if your actual data is an `int` instead of a string, please update your question.

Comment: Hm, the string I am dealing with is the block I have up there labeled HEX String. It's a string.